# New Firebase Crashlytics disable in debug mode

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have recently switched to new Firebase Crashlytics from Fabric one and I can't find alternative for disabling Crashlytics in debug mode.

Fabric:

```
val crashlytics = Crashlytics.Builder().core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build()
Fabric.with(this, crashlytics, Answers())
```

Anyone know answer? Ive seen that `FirebaseCrashlytics` class has its core set up internally now. I've tried `FirebaseCrashlytics(CrashlyticsCore.??).getInstance()`, but that kind of constructor is not working.

Also `CrashlyticsCore` class no longer has `.Builder()` available

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I have tried once some time ago which worked for me . Add this to `build.gradle`.

```
android {
  buildTypes {
     debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"false"]
        ...
     }

    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

And then set this attribute in manifest .

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

If you log manually also then you can use something like this at runtime :-

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(RuntimeException("Invalidtoken"))
```

Also  [Check this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?hl=da&platform=android#kotlin+ktx) and [crashlytics opt-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting).

Comment: More safe way to add manifest placeholders in place of replace all of them will be: `manifestPlaceholders.firebasecrashlyticsCollectionEnabled = false`

Comment: @sosite can you please tell me in which tag i should add this line?

Comment: @Tanjimahmed You use it directly in `debug` or `release` build types

Comment: @wrozwad For the given example it should be `manifestPlaceholders. crashlyticsCollectionEnabled = false` - or alternatively `manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = false`.

Answer (score 88):

To do it programmatically use below code in Application class

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
//enabled only for signed builds
```

> Enable collection for select users by calling the Crashlytics data collection override at runtime. The override value persists across launches of your app so Crashlytics can automatically collect reports for future launches of that app instance. To opt out of automatic crash reporting, pass false as the override value. When set to false, the new value does not apply until the next run of the app.

Here is the link to documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting

Comment: To disable the crash logs while in debug mode you must pass `!BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

Enabled only for signed builds
`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);`
So the value will be false and it will only log crash for release build.

Comment: Since Crashlytics is enabled by default, I prefer this:
`if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
 FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
}`

Answer (score 4):

#### This works for me

###### manifest.xml

```
<meta-data             
   android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"            
   android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

###### build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = true
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = false
        }
    }
```

check from official docs:

**[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting)** and **[Inject build variables into the manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#inject_build_variables_into_the_manifest)**